# How to symbolize this statement?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Let us define
\begin{align}
m &: \mbox{ Maria} \\
s &: \mbox{ Maria's son} \\
C &: \mbox{ works in the city} \\
B &: \mbox{ rides a bicycle} \\
F &: \mbox{ is a chicken farmer}.
\end{align}

Then how to symbolize the following two statements?

1. If no-one working in the city rides a bicycle then Maria doesn't work in the city and her son is not a chicken farmer.
2. No chicken farmers work in the city and ride a bicycle.

My Attempt:

1.

> The statement "no-one working in the city rides a bicycle" can be rephrased as

> For every x, if $x$ works in the city then $x$ doesn't ride a bicycle.

> This can be symbolized as
> $$ \forall x \left[ C(x) \rightarrow \overline{B(x)}\right]. $$

So the given statement can be symbolized as
$$
\left[ \forall x \left\{ C(x) \rightarrow \overline{B(x)} \right\} \right] \rightarrow \left[ \overline{C(m)} \land \overline{F(s)} \right]. 
$$

2.

> The given statement can be rephrased as

For every $x$, if $x$ is a chicken farmer then it is not the case that $x$ works in the city and rides a bicycle.

So the given statement can be symbolized as
$$
\forall x \left[ F(x) \rightarrow \left\{ \overline{C(x) \land B(x)} \right\} \right]. 
$$

Are my solutions correct?

Comment: I like that question ! An upvote !

Comment: I think it's correct.

Comment: It is ok. Note that in set notation you can formulate $\forall x[P(x)\to\overline{Q(x)}]$ as $P\cap Q=\varnothing$. Thus 2. is just $F\cap C\cap B=\varnothing$. For more examples of quantifiers/natural language transcription you can look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2152552/399263